# How to add values of the same item in a column?

Tags: sql

I have the following columns in a table:

1. Product Name
2. Quantity
3. Description

I want to add the quantities of the product if the name of the product is same. For example if I have product with the same name twice, I want the total quantities of the products to be added and get a result.

This is the table and I want to add the quantities of the same item:

```
Name            Quantity   Description
Pen              3 
Pencil           2
Pen              6
Eraser           7
Eraser           6
```

For exmaple:

- I have pen twice and so want to add (3+6) and the display the total as 9, and ...
- I have eraser twice (7+6), so the total should be 13.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Quantity) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name
```

`GROUP BY` is used in an SQL query to group rows together for aggregation purposes.
For example:
If your input table had rows:

```
ItemName       Qty
Pen            4
Pencil         7
Pen            6
```

SQL Code:

```
SELECT ItemName, SUM(Qty) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY ItemName
```

Using `GROUP BY ItemName` in your query would give you the output:

```
ItemName       Qty
Pen            10
Pencil         7
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` reduces the same valued rows (i.e: same `Name`d) to 1 row. And `SUM` function add the column values that are grouped. Info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name
```

This is the best example!

Comment: I doubt this is the best exmple, it doesnt even select the `Name` column

Comment: yes but i dont konw your table name i only show you code part

Comment: I meant the COLUMN with the name `Name` as the OP requests. Anyway, Snow Blind already gave the correct answer.